# NodeJS & SSL - "bad password read"

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, certificate

Node is failing to create a secure context for SSL communications.

Specifically, I'm trying to get remote notifications to work on iOS. I use a module, called node-apn which throws this error:

```
Error: error:0906A068:PEM routines:PEM_do_header:bad password read
at Error (native)
at Object.createSecureContext (_tls_common.js:108:19)
at Object.exports.connect (_tls_wrap.js:852:21)
at apnSocket (/home/Slurp/node_modules/apn/lib/socket.js:56:19)
at Connection.<anonymous> (/home/Slurp/node_modules/apn/lib/connection.js:188:17)
at _fulfilled (/home/Slurp/node_modules/apn/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
at self.promiseDispatch.done (/home/Slurp/node_modules/apn/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/Slurp/node_modules/apn/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
```

This seems to be a generic error though, and isn't really related to APN specifically.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

This is because you've specified a passphrase when generating the cert. This is a password that must be supplied by anyone wanting to use it.

Adding a passphrase field to the credentials solves the problem.

```
var credentials = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('XXX.key', 'utf8'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('XXX.crt', 'utf8'),
    passphrase: 'XXXX'
}

var httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);
```

Comment: Is this passphrase used to create the `.pem` or  '.crt' files?

Comment: I think it was used to create the .crt file

Answer (score 10):

The following command will generate an unencrypted key, so you won't need to provide a passphrase:

```
openssl rsa -in yourKey.key -out newKey.key
```

This command will prompt you for the passphrase.

Answer (score 0):

Use these to generate pem.

`openssl genrsa -out server-key.pem 1024
openssl req -new -key server-key.pem -out server-csr.pem
openssl x509 -req -in server-csr.pem -signkey server-key.pem -out server-cert.pem`