# Unable to start Angular 7 with SSL certificate connecting to spring cloud applications - PEM_READ_BIO_PRIVATEKEY:bad password read

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, spring-security, spring-cloud, angular7

we are developing a Spring cloud application with microservice architecture and have a self signed certificate.We have written the code and completed the SSL settings in back end successfully.
Now we try to set up the certificate in front end in Angular 7.
we made the following changes
1.Generated the SSL .crt and .key files.placed in SSL folder
2.Modified Angular.json file and included

```
 "ssl": true,
 "sslKey": "ssl/server.key",
 "sslCert": "ssl/server.crt"
```

but when I start i am getting the following error

```
error:0907B068:PEM routines:PEM_READ_BIO_PRIVATEKEY:bad password read
```

I have found 2 helpful links

1. [NodeJS & SSL - "bad password read"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30957793/nodejs-ssl-bad-password-read)
2. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1576

Please note that I don't want these two solutions

1.Running the front end code in back end server by placing the Angular 7 code in static folder
 2.Removing the passphrase from the key.

Link1 says that we need to add the code

```
var credentials = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('XXX.key', 'utf8'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('XXX.crt', 'utf8'),
    passphrase: 'XXXX'
}
```

but where in Angular 7 we need to add the these settings

Thanks
Mahidhar

Comment: Please share your solution if you were able to resolve this issue.